# Parse exception dataframe collect action SPARK

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

What is wrong in the following dataframe collect action?

```py
version = spark.sql("select max(version) as latest_version from (DESCRIBE HISTORY {})".format(table_name)).collect()[0][0]
```

It shows an exception as follows

```
ParseException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2270449224428357> in <module>
      5 #   table_name = database_name+"."+(all_params.get(param_dict)).get('dim_table_name')
      6   table_name = "hive_metastore"+"."+database_name+"."+(all_params.get(param_dict)).get('dim_table_name')
----> 7   version = spark.sql("select max(version) as latest_version from (DESCRIBE HISTORY {})".format(table_name)).collect()[0][0]
      8   version_dict.update({table_name: version})
```

Comment: there should be more helpful error text in the traceback. please share the same as well

Comment: By plain SQL standard, you probably missing an alias in subselect?